# How to copy one Maven Pom.xml dependencies to other Pom.xml

Tags: maven-2

Is there any way I can copy one pom.xml dependencies into other pom.xml

**Update:** Well, I have project A and Project B.

Project B is using some dependencies ( like Junit.jar, commons-httpclient, commons-collections, struts)

In the Project A : I would like to copy all project B dependencies in some out folder

This I can specify manually all dependencies jars of Project B in Project A but I would like to do automatically some script in Project A pom.xml.

Note: I don't want to build the project B in Project A pom.xml , I am building Project B separately

Does this make any sense?

Comment: can you elaborate on the relationship between the two maven projects?

Comment: I've merged your *multiple* accounts together. [Please read this Faq entry about cookie-based accounts.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account/44562#44562) Also, StackOverflow isn't a forum; if you have a new question, please ask a new question. If you want to include more information in your question, please [edit it](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/2828446/edit). If you want to interact with one of the people who has answered, you can leave them a comment.

Answer (score 1):

While I understand the spirit of the question (and only the spirit), the relation between project A and project B is still unclear so I'm not sure of the best way to implement this. Here are the options.

First solution: leverage [transitive dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies). There are some rules about them, but basically, if you declare a dependency on Project B in Project A, you'll get some of its dependencies transitively.

Second solution: use inheritance.

Third option: use another project of type `pom` to group the dependencies and declare a dependency on this pom.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand  well what you mean, keep only the dependencies in project B pom.xml. If you need something else in this pom, create another directory level B1, and push every other elements in it. Then makes B pom.xml a pom packaging with one module:B1.

Then you can make project B pom.xml the parent of project A pom.xml. A will inherit dependencies from B.

Answer (score 1):

I think the maven invoker plugin does pretty much exactly what you need:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/install-mojo.html

---

Or create a java class using the maven API, programmatically build a maven project and export the dependencies

start here:
http://maven.apache.org/ref/2.2.1/maven-project/apidocs

read a model:
http://maven.apache.org/ref/2.0.11/maven-model/apidocs/org/apache/maven/model/io/xpp3/MavenXpp3Reader.html

construct a MavenProject object using the model:
http://maven.apache.org/ref/2.2.1/maven-project/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/MavenProject.html#MavenProject(org.apache.maven.model.Model%29

resolve and export the dependencies

Sean